# Can return types from generic functions be instead converted to a typealias?

Tags: swift, generics, type-alias

Starting with the following two protocols for `TypedPoint` and `TypedVector`...

```swift
public protocol TypedPoint {
    
    associatedtype TUnit: Numeric

    init(x: TUnit, y: TUnit);
 
    var x: TUnit { get set }
    var y: TUnit { get set }
}

public protocol TypedVector {

    associatedtype TUnit: Numeric

    init(dx: TUnit, dy: TUnit);

    var dx: TUnit { get set }
    var dy: TUnit { get set }
}
```

Take a look at these two extension methods.  Note how they specify the exact same return type represented with a generic constraint and a 'where' clause?

```swift
public extension TypedPoint {

    static func +<TVector>(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> TVector
    where TVector: TypedVector,
          TVector.TUnit == TUnit {
        
        let dx = lhs.x + rhs.x
        let dy = lhs.y + rhs.y
        
        return TVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }

    static func -<TVector>(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> TVector
    where TVector: TypedVector,
          TVector.TUnit == TUnit {
        
        let dx = lhs.x - rhs.x
        let dy = lhs.y - rhs.y
        
        return TVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }
}
```

What I'm hoping for is rather than to define each as a generic function, since you know all that's needed for the constraint (i.e. that `TVector` is a kind of `TypedVector` where `TUnit` matches the one on `TypedPoint` itself) if you could instead define the return type as typealias and use that in the call-site (see below.)  However, I can't seem to figure out how to do it or if it's even possible.

Trying the following doesn't compile and I can't seem to find syntax that will.

```swift
public extension TypedPoint {

    typealias Vector = TypedVector where TypedVector.TUnit == TUnit

    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> TVector {
        
        let dx = lhs.x + rhs.x
        let dy = lhs.y + rhs.y
        
        return TVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }

    static func -(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> TVector {
        
        let dx = lhs.x - rhs.x
        let dy = lhs.y - rhs.y
        
        return TVector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
    }
}
```

So can this be done?

Comment: Why does the vector protocol use the same associated type as the point protocol? Shouldn't a vector contain point objects instead? For instance `associatedtype TUnit: TypedPoint`

Comment: I also in general think it's a bit strange adding two values of a specific type together will generate a new type, specially when using the `+` operator. I fully understand that you want to make a vector from two points but that is not done with addition (math) imo.